# Webmatrix - Reusable database insert query

Tags: sql, function, razor, webmatrix

i have a SQL query (shown below), that i need to regularly run on 5 different pages. My question is, is there a way that i can write this once, and call it on each page (maybe using a function or a helper)?

```
    if(IsPost){
    var ImageCount = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Property_Images WHERE PropertyID = @0", rPropertyId);
    var RateCount =  db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM RateInfo WHERE PropertyID = @0", rPropertyId);
    var ExpiryDate = db.QueryValue("SELECT ExpiryDate FROM Property_Info WHERE PropertyID = @0", rPropertyId);


    if(ImageCount > 0 && RateCount > 0 && ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now){
        db.Execute("UPDATE Property_Info SET IsActive = 1 WHERE PropertyID = @0", rPropertyId);
    } else {
        db.Execute("UPDATE Property_Info SET IsActive = 0 WHERE PropertyID = @0", rPropertyId);
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

I have used functions before to re-use SQL queries, but i have always assigned them as a 'bool', as the result is either true or force, but this isn't the case with this particular query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods can return void (or nothing). Your current code transcribed to a function might look like this:

```
@functions{
    public static void UpdateProperty(int propertyId, Uri url){
        var db = Database.Open("....");
        var ImageCount = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Property_Images WHERE PropertyID = @0", propertyId);
        var RateCount =  db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM RateInfo WHERE PropertyID = @0", propertyId);
        var ExpiryDate = db.QueryValue("SELECT ExpiryDate FROM Property_Info WHERE PropertyID = @0", propertyId);


        if(ImageCount > 0 && RateCount > 0 && ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now){
            db.Execute("UPDATE Property_Info SET IsActive = 1 WHERE PropertyID = @0", propertyId);
        } else {
            db.Execute("UPDATE Property_Info SET IsActive = 0 WHERE PropertyID = @0", propertyId);
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
Is(IsPost){
    Functions.UpdateProperty(rPropertyId, Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: i've seen static void used so much in examples, but never fully understood what it meant, so thank you so much! I'll give this a go straight away!

Comment: Mike, i'm getting this error "The best overloaded method match for 'ASP.Functions.ActiveCheck(int)' has some invalid arguments" any idea why?

Comment: Ignore me, it was one of those "user errors"! working a treat now, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Cannot you use a SPROC instead? you could also return output parameters in case you need them

```
 string SQL = "exec dbo.myprocname @0";
 db.Execute(SQL, rPropertyId);
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify what kind of SQL Server is used. Stored Procedure could be a solution, but not with SQL Ce.

Comment: yep, that's why I asked him if he could use them... if he can, I still think it would be a better solution to have all the sql in the sproc